# Select Children of an object with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this function that I'm using to open a modal dialog that I need to populate with some information from the 'dblclicked' node:

```
$(function(){
    $(".delete").live('dblclick', function () {
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#delID').val(id);
        var txt = this.parentNode.children[2].innerHTML;
        $("#details").html(txt);
        $("#delAssign").dialog('open');
    });
});
```

Example of the html:

```
<tr>
    <td class='delete'></td>
    <td></td>
    ...
    <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
...
</tr>
```

Right now I'm getting the

```
var txt = ...
```

with pure javaScript.

The question is "How can I achieve the same result for the var txt using jQuery?"

Comment: please provide the associated html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change it to:

```
var txt = $(this).siblings(":eq(2)").html();
```

I think it's the fastest solution.

Comment: Siblings with `eq` won't always work because `this` is not included.  This may throw off indexing if `this` comes at the beginning.  You need to use `:nth-child(2)` instead.

Comment: jQuery handles its $(this) object very well. It will always work on DOM objects found in $(".delete") . Anyway you are wrong about :nth-child :). nth-child starts counting from 1 and :eq from 0 so if you want to use :nth-child then index should be 3.

Comment: What @Dennis means is that `.siblings` does not return all children of the parent. Example: Imagine `this` is the third child. So `:eq(2)` should return itself. But `$(this).siblings(":eq(2)")` would return the forth node as `$(this).siblings` excludes `this`.

Comment: Thanks @avall the `.siblings()` really did the job!! I just needed to change one thing: since `$(this)` is the `<td>` and I'm not using the `parentNone` anymore I had to change the `(":eq(2)")` to `(":eq(1)")`

Comment: My bad. Dennis is right about not including "this" :). Well, learning all the time!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
var txt = $(this).parent().children().eq(2).html();
```

`.parent()` selects the parent element.

`.children()` selects the children

`.eq(2)` selects the element with index `2` within the children

`.html()`  gets the html content of this element

**edit:** changed `children(':eq(2)')` to `children().eq(2)` thanks to Felix Kling

Comment: You have wrong syntax - :eq  pseudoclass uses ()  instead of []

Comment: Ah okay. I looked at your legend only :)

Comment: Even better if you do `children().eq(2)`.

Comment: Thanks @Kokos, your answer worked like a charm! I was missing the pseudoclass `:eq(2)`

Answer (score 0):

```
var txt = $(this).siblings().eq(2).html();
```

Using `eq()` as a method instead of passing it as the selector is faster.

Anyway, since you already had the solution in JavaScript, why you want to slow down things using jQuery?